# Match cut-string mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I match cut string from mysql

For exampe in the column the value is googleduo or googlehangout, but the string I have is google.

> SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$string."%' LIMIT 1

This doesnt return record. At least it return one by finding the closest time

OR maybe the case is vice-versa, I have string googleduo, but the value in the table is google. I want to return google.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM table WHERE LOCATE(string, name)`

Comment: it works. Should be accepted answer. Thanks. I have no idea if it is ever exist

Comment: @Akina , how about the vice-versa condition?

Answer (score 2):

if you need to check does the substring is present in the column value use one of:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE LOCATE(substring, name);
-- or
SELECT name FROM table WHERE INSTR(name, substring);
```

The functions returns the position of the substring in the column value if present and `0` otherwise. Non-zero is treated as TRUE, zero as FALSE.

The functions do absolutely the same and differs in parameters order only.

If you need backward condition then simply add NOT:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE NOT LOCATE(substring, name);
-- or
SELECT name FROM table WHERE ! LOCATE(substring, name);
```